# Getting a warning when using VS Code and not getting the correct answer

Tags: c++, clang

I am getting this warning on my Visual Studio Code when I am running code related to classes. I am using Mac and Clang as my compiler. Hope some one can help me. Thank you.

Comment: Your question is not showing any warning. Make sure to have everything needed for the question. It would also help to copy/paste the error as text, not just a screenshot (if that's what you are trying to add). BTW, what does _"code related to classes"_ exactly mean? That's pretty vague.

Comment: show your code and the warning, the class can be 5 lines or 500 lines